# Where is /etc/network/interfaces on Yocto?

Tags: networking, yocto-project

I try to find `/etc/network/interfaces` file on intell edisson. It is not there. Where is network interfaces configuration file on Yocto?

Comment: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#migration-1.4-custom-interfaces-file-netbase-change

Answer (score 2):

Let yocto locate it for you. Source your environment and then

```
x> cd $BUILDDIR
build_fb> oe-pkgdata-util find-path /etc/network/interfaces
init-ifupdown: /etc/network/interfaces
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, edison BSP uses connman for managing internet